# SUMIFS Excel using "is an element of" as a condition

Tags: excel, sumifs

Is it possible to do a SUMIFS statement with one of the conditions being:  sum column E where column A is any one of x,y,z

e.g.
SUMIFS(E2:E8744,A2:A8744,"in(x,y,z)")

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Also note that you can use `SUMIF` instead of `SUMIFS` in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

`=SUM(SUMIFS(E2:E8744,A2:A8744,{"x","y","z"}))`

The SUMIFS function returns an "array" of 3 values - one each for "x", "y" and "z" - so you then need the SUM function to sum that array and get the total

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is like this:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E8744,A2:A8744,"=x") + SUMIFS(E2:E8744,A2:A8744,"=y") + SUMIFS(E2:E8744,A2:A8744,"=z")
```

You can also use an array function like this:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A8744="x",E2:E8744,IF(A2:A8744="y",E2:E8744,IF(A2:A8744="z",E2:E8744,0))))
```

When entering the formula above you must use Ctrl + Shift + Enter to complete the formula and not just the Enter key.

Comment: The second formula won't work because OR always returns a single value not an array, you can use + to simulate OR, i.e. `=SUM(IF((A2:A8744="X")+(A2:A8744="Y")+(A2:A8744="Z"),E2:E8744))`

Comment: @barry houdini - you're right should have tested first. Have changed the second formula to a version that does work.